# How to ensure user accepts terms and conditions on ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net

We're modifying an existing ASP.NET application.  We added a Terms and Conditions page with an "Accept" button that stores that choice in the user's account data.  We want to prevent the user from accessing any page when the user has not accepted the Terms and Conditions.

I think we want to do this by looking up the "accepted terms" value upon login and storing it in the session.  Then we need to intercept every request and check for that session value.  (If it's not there, we redirect the user to the Terms and Conditions page.)

Is the PreRequestHandlerExecute method the right place to put this check?  This method also gets called on requests for stylesheets and images, so it doesn't seem like it was intended for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PreRequestHandlerExecute is the easiest handler that I've found so far. I'll typically use it when I need to assess the value of Session variables before every request, which is similar to what you're doing.

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState) {
    // Business Logic Here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the short way out and put a disclaimer on your login page that by logging in, the user agrees to the (link)Terms and Conditions.(/link) One place I worked, Legal was fine with that and I've seen it plenty of other places.

Comment: Now that's the best kind of solution!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the membership and role providers? You could define a role for users who have accepted the T&Cs and limit access to that role through web.config or other means. Another advantage of this approach is that you could define additional roles if (when) T&Cs change and easily force users to accept the new T&Cs.

Comment: That's a fairly straight-forward suggestion.  The only problem is that it would produce a rather ugly authorization error rather than simply redirecting the user to the terms and conditions.

Comment: @Jeremy: Why? You can check if they're in the role at login and redirect to your T&C page if not. I can only see it being an issue if users are frequently redirected to requested pages after login instead of a landing page. Even so, your 403 page could check the role and provide a useful error message.

Comment: True, it shouldn't normally happen.  And in our case, we can't change the 403 page.

Answer (score 1):

It is a generic handler, so it gets called for everything. Just put a bit of logic at the top of your handler that exits if it isn't a page you want to control access to.

Comment: Really?  That's the right place to put the access control?  We've found that we can't reliably access the session from there, and this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111827

Comment: Woah. I hadn't run across that. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement and what I did was to put my validation logic in a base class and make all forms that need this validation inherit my base class.

That way the validation only runs on forms I want, no problems with requests to static content etc...