# PreRequestHandlerExecute not called for redirected Pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

Using Global.asax's PreRequestHandlerExecute to handle themes dynamically.

When using the below, the PreRequestHandlerExecute is only executed for the previous page, and not the now-loading page:

```
    Server.Transfer(~/Error.aspx", True)
```

This results in my theme not being used for the Error.aspx page, as the PreRequestHandlerExecute wasn't handled for this page.

Anyone know why? Can't seem to find any answers.

Question also here, but unanswered (and 4 years old):  [Why is PreRequestHandlerExecute not called after postback redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111827/why-is-prerequesthandlerexecute-not-called-after-postback-redirect)

Update: Have read that Server.Transfer continues the current request, whereas an alternative like Response.Redirect cancels the current request, and makes another. This makes sense if the same request is being used (as we've already handled the event for this request). In that case... Any work arounds available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ansower is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800(v=vs.90).aspx):

> Server.Transfer acts as an efficient replacement for the
>   Response.Redirect method. Response.Redirect specifies to the browser
>   to request a different page. Because a redirect forces a new page
>   request, the browser makes two requests to the Web server, so the Web
>   server handles an extra request. IIS 5.0 introduced a new function,
>   Server.Transfer, which transfers execution to a different ASP page on
>   the server. This avoids the extra request, resulting in better overall
>   system performance, as well as a better user experience.

Server.Transfer does not start a new Request so PreRequestHandlerExecute is not executed. Use Response.Redirect if you need to start a new Request. Or set the Theme in the page in another event (Page_PreInit for instance).

Comment: I thought as much. Too bad there seems to be no implementation for a universal change that fixes every page - fortunately I only access one page using Server.Transfer, so this change is okay for me. Thanks. I'll make as answer for now until any other suggestions are made.